# How to remove the arrow of treeView

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, treeviewitem, radtreeview

I am under a situation (using silverlight5) where i am asked to remove the arrow of Treeview. By Arrow i mean this symbol `">"` (which is often in left of Parent). It is actually a RadTreeView and obtained by doing this :

```
<telerik:RadTreeView Name="RadTreeViewObj" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="50" Background="{StaticResource BGBrush_1}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BGBrush_1}" ItemsSource="{Binding EODDataStepsCollection}" SelectionMode="Single" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}">
    <telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding RelatedItems}">
            //Something UI elemnts here
        </telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

For examlpe this:
(In Lest of Clearing Prices i have a symbol) . And i have been asked to remove it.

[image]

First of all, Is it possible to remove this arrow ? If yes, Then how to do it ?

Secondly How to reduce the space between the two Childrens ? I mean i want the children to display very close to each other (vertically less space between children as compared to two consecutive Parents on closing the the tree Parent).

Comment: You should split your question in two postings: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: Ok i am sorry; i WILL take care in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the visibility of the expander element:

```
radTreeView1.NodeFormatting += radTreeView1_NodeFormatting;

         private void radTreeView1_NodeFormatting(object sender,TreeNodeFormattingEventArgs e)
     {
             e.NodeElement.ExpanderElement.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Hidden; 
     }
```

If you prefer to use an xaml approach you can create an expander style and use the ExpanderStyle property of the RadTreeView. The style would simply set the visiblity of the toggle button.

On the Telerik page you find more [details](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radtreeview-styling-and-appearance-styling-expander.html).

Comment: Is it possible in Xaml ? Bceuase i am working in xaml.

Comment: And do you know i have to make this arrow disappear from starting. hat you mean is i guess after that arrow lcik youwant to make it disapper if i am right.

Comment: The NodeFormatting is called for all nodes before the grid is rendered.

Comment: Same error for NodeFormatting  and TreeNodeFormattingEventArgs = Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadTreeView' does not contain a definition for 'NodeFormatting' and no extension method 'NodeFormatting' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadTreeView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: and also its a silverlight application not WinForm. So i guess do not exist for silverlight